# applying function with passed in arguments as well as own supplied

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm not sure of the technical term of what I'm trying to do so it makes it hard for me to find information. So what I'm trying to do is to pass known future arguments to a function, while also needing to pass a particular argument.

E.g.

```
app.post("/example", function (req, res) { 
    admin.retrieveMany(req, res, "list") 
});
```

So what I require in the future is the `req` `res` parameters, but at the same time, I need to pass a particular argument, in this case `"list"`.

Is there a way to do this without needing a wrapper function? so just something like `admin.retrieveMany(...args, "list")`?

**Update:**

This is how my `admin` is exported

```
module.exports.admin = {
    create,
    drop,
    retrieveMany
}
```

This is the create function summarised:

```
function create(req, res, which) {
    try {
        var { name } = mixin.getProxy(req.body, res)
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
        return
    }
    // SQL stuff
}
```

Proxy code:

```
function getProxy(obj, res) {
    return new Proxy(obj, { //create new Proxy object
        get: function (obj, prop) { //define get trap
            if (prop in obj) {
                return obj[prop];
            }
            else {
                if (res) {
                    res.send({
                        error: true,
                        error_message: "could not retrieve prop: " + prop,
                        success: false
                    })
                }
                throw new Error("Missing required key: " + prop); //throw error if prop doesn't exists
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: The technical term you are looking for is a partial or partial function.

Comment: @Mark_M do you think `apply` would be applicable in this case?

Comment: I think you want `bind` as @CertainPerformance suggests in the answer. `Apply` returns the result of the function, `bind` returns a new function with some of the args already in place.

Comment: Try to find out `bind()`, `apply()` or `call()`

Answer (score 0):

How about `bind`? Change `retrieveMany` so that its first argument is whatever `list` represents, and then

```
app.post("/example", admin.retrieveMany.bind(admin, "list"));
```

Comment: sorry, I don't quite understand, could you expand your explanation?

Comment: `bind` allows you to create a new function from another, only with set arguments (and a `this` value, if needed), which sounds like exactly what you're looking for here...?

Comment: `admin` is actually an object. I'm also using a Proxy to retrieve keys from (so I can throw errors if one is missing). I'm currently getting the error `TypeError: Cannot create proxy with a non-object as target or handler`. So I'm not sure how to implement your method into my code.

Comment: If `admin` is just an import/export object and `retrieveMany`'s functionality doesn't depend on other properties on the object, then you can drop the `admin` from it and try this instead: `app.post("/example", admin.retrieveMany.bind(null, "list"));`. But I don't know how you're defining `retrieveMany`.